# Install wifi drivers without internet

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell, xps

I just got my new XPS 15 Laptop.
The problem now is that I installed ubuntu as soon as I got it, then I realized that I don't have an internet connection.
[Image of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0mKI.jpg)
So I went searching.
I found [this site](https://dev.to/mathieugagne/ubuntu-20-04-on-dell-xps-15-9500-3920) on which step 3 seemed helpful to me. So I tried installing the packages to a thumb drive with the `sudo download ...` command. On the XPS I then tried to install them with `sudo dpkg -i ...` This gave me the error

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of build-essential:
build-essential depends on libc6-dev | libc-dev: however:
Package libc6-dev in not installed. 
...
...
dpkg: error processing package build-essential (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I also tried to install the Linux OEM thing which also gave me a similar error message. If it helps [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqhUS.jpg) the full error messages.

When I type in `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` I get

```
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:43f0] (rev 11)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1651]
    Kernel modules iwlwifi
0000:00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: INtel Corporation Device [8086:43e8] (rev 11)
```

`lsb_release` gives me:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID : Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.02.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
```

`uname -r` is
5.8.0-43-generic

I also tried to install the things explained [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000058910/wireless/intel-wireless-products.html). But when I install the packages on my laptop I get many of those  `dpkg: dependency problem` errors and then a `Errors were encountered while processing:` with a list of all things that didn't work/couldn't be installed (this all happened on my offline laptop with the 4th last code line on this website)

I would like to know if

1. Am I on the right track so do I even have to install a driver or what do I need to do to have WiFi
2. is this the right thing to do to install my driver and
3. What do I have to do to get rid of that error
   I'm rather new to the whole linux world so please don't judge me if I didn't find the most obvious answer by googling and I now have to ask here...
   Thanks in advance for your responses

Comment: *linux-oem-20.04* which is referenced in the link, is a package whose dependencies install complete OEM Linux kernel and headers (dummy transitional package). I am unaware of any wireless driver that it installs other than those included in every default install. Let's start by identifying your exact wireless device. Please edit your question to show the result of the teminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Updated it, thanks already for looking over it again :)

Comment: "8086:43f0" Ahhh, the good old 43f0. Lucky you! The readings show that the driver iwlwifi is present and covers your device but is not yet loaded. Let's load it and check the log for messages which should give us some helpful clues: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` As the output is likely lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: May I also see, in an edit: `lsb_release -a` and `uname -r` Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/HXYwSCfVd8/ here the results of your command the other things I updated in the question, thanks again for looking over it, I would be so happy if it would work!

Comment: Please see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1913259 This is your exact device and your exact error! "Direct firmware load for (efault)60.ucode failed with error -2" There is no such firmware named efault. The bug report suggests that the issue is fixed in Ubuntu 21.04. I suggest that you try a live session and see if the wireless is working.

Comment: @chili555 Yes installing Ubuntu 21.04 worked for me. What do you know what the exact error is so I may be able to resolve it when I install another distro or is this just a Ubuntu 20.04 thing? Sorry for answering so late...

Comment: As far as I know, it's a kernel version issue. In any distro, I'd look for exactly what I quoted: "Direct firmware load for (efault)60.ucode failed with error -2" (efault) is, I think, the clue.